# How to configure SSL for subversion access in windows?

Tags: windows, ssl, svn, authentication

As the question describes, can anyone point to a good documentation or if possible give me the basic steps to configure a  windows subversion server (1.4.3) please?

I already have subversion, apache and svnserve running on the server. The existing users within the LAN are already on SSPI authentication. I need to get a few new, non-domain, non-NTLM users to access the existing repositories. I dont want to use the svn:// with passwd configuration as this transmits data and password in cleartext over the network. SSPI does not work for these users outside the LAN. So that goes out of the window as well.

I am looking to see if SSL access is feasible in our situation. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered having your users tunnel via SSH?

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshauth

Answer (score 0):

If you can access subversion now over HTTP, then simply follow the docs to add SSL support to apache: http://tud.at/programm/apache-ssl-win32-howto.php3